# Is there a politer way of saying 'don't get you panties in a bunch'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm from India, and here this phrase is likely to offend people, especially women. I'm looking for a phrase that means '*Don't worry*' in a similarly colorful, humorous way.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a humorous phrase, not common ones like 'chill', or 'relax' and their derivatives.

Comment: I've always said: *Don't get your knickers in a twist* never a *bunch*.

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/ways-of-telling-someone-not-to-worry-or-be-upset

Comment: Are you wanting a specifically Indian English phrase?

Comment: @curiousdannii: No mate. We Indians can speak English pretty well. "I'm wanting" a phrase the humour of which doesn't rely on some obscure reference we Indians can't understand.

Comment: Take two aspirin and call me in the morning.

Comment: "Don't get so worked up", "Don't tie yourself in knots", "Don't tie your hair in knots", "Don't pull your hair out", "You have a bee in your bonnet", "Don't worry about the bee in your bonnet"

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's

> ["Don't have a cow, man!"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+have+a+cow!),

but that might have a similarly negative impact.  I use

> "Calm down, Charlie Brown!",

which is a reference to the gag from the [Peanuts comic strips](http://www.gocomics.com/peanuts/2012/09/11) where Charlie occasionally lost his cool.  There's also a derivation (possibly the origination) of "panties in a bunch", which is

> "Don't get your knickers in a knot!"

Has a nice ring to it, and might not turn as many heads.

> ["Take a chill pill!"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+a+chill+pill)

is another common one.

Comment: It's India, you can't disrespect cows! And few would understand the Peanuts reference here. The third one is basically the same phrase.

Comment: Take a chill pill is actually nice. That phrase was popularized by Shah Rukh Khan in the Bollywood movie Happiness and Tears (2001). It was in vogue back then, but it's considered old-fashioned by the youngsters today.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for sharing :)  Unfortunately I'm spent for ideas at this point, good luck in your search!

Comment: Sorry about that. +1 for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try this expression. It's not humorous *per se*, but it's been pretty popular lately. For example:

"What! Are you saying you left your wallet at home?"

[image: Keep calm and carry on.]

Note that delivery is key to pulling this off.

Comment: IMO, it works best visually. Not the same impact when you say it. Plus, since this is a British Army reference, I'm not sure many Indians will get it.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a kid in Houston, I used to listen to what was then known as the "soul station" on the radio, where you could hear not only older Mo-town songs, but all the latest Soul Train dance songs, Joe Simon ballads, and the like. Anyway, one of the DJs had an expression that I've always appreciated because it struck me as both funny and very hip:

> Just continue to maintain your cool.

If someone said that to you in a groovy yet reassuring way, how could you not?